# Can't get controller to load correctly in tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to get a controller to load correctly in a tab.
I have tried in the module the following to load the controller in the tab.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        data: {
            'selectedTab' : 0
        },
        templateUrl: 'main.html'            
    })
    .state('main.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        data: {
            'selectedTab' : 1
        },
        templateUrl: 'tab1.html',
        controller: 'MembersCtrl as vm'         
    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: '/contact',
        data: {
            'selectedTab' : 2
        },
        templateUrl: 'tab2.html'
    });
```

When I load the tab nothing seems to happen when I invoke the register function in the controller.
Is there another approach I can try.

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('main.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        data: {
            'selectedTab' : 1
        },
        templateUrl: 'tab1.html',
        controller: 'MembersCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm' // here's where you set it
    })
```